# ProGuard output does not run

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I have built a jar, which runs without problems. ProGuard processing was also successful:

```
C:\Users\alexk>C:\proguard5.2.1\bin\proguard.bat @M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\config.pro
ProGuard, version 5.2.1
Reading program jar [M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\jgetrealv.jar]
Reading library jar [M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\JGetRealVConsoleApp\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar]
Reading library jar [M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\JGetRealVConsoleApp\slf4j-jdk14-1.7.21.jar]
Reading library jar [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\rt.jar]
Preparing output jar [M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\jgetrealv_out.jar]
Copying resources from program jar [M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\jgetrealv.jar]
```

But when I try to run the output jar, I get an error:

```
C:\Users\alexk>java -jar M:\JGetRealV_alexk\JVAUtilities\jgetrealv_out.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by adding the following lines to config.pro:

```
-keep class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

A lot of thanks to Eric Lafortune (https://sourceforge.net/u/lafortune/), who has sent this solution.